# Creating an Object Detection model with images and coordinates of bounding boxes

Tags: dataset, image-classification, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to build a custom Object Detection model which can detect guns from a given image. The dataset is from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/issaisasank/guns-object-detection).

The dataset has a good number of images and each image has 4 coordinates of bounding boxes with it. I recently read about YOLO and the structure of its labels is as follows:

[image: YOLO labels]

I need to get this label for every grid cell of the input image. **The dataset which I have contains coordinates for the object and not a grid cell in the image.**

> Also, I can manage to get `bx, by, bh, bw` and `c1 , c2 , c3`, but how
>   do I extract `pc` for training from the dataset?

I will like to build a YOLO model from scratch but I don't know how to transform the dataset so that I can train a YOLO on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer myself. Basically, if the grid cell contains the centre of the bounding box then the grid cell will have a $p_c$ of 1 otherwise 0 if there is no object.